# Asp.Net Web Forms application deployment to Production server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

What is the recommended method/tool to deploy an ASP.NET Web Forms project and/or a Database Project to production server ?

Currently I'm using VS2012 web deploy publishing feature.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.110).aspx

web deploy is the recommended method/tool.